# Overriding "Woocommerce Shipment Tracking" plugin templates files

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have been trying to override a template in the "Woocommerce Shippment Tracking" plugin: 
 `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-shipment-tracking/templates/email/tracking-info.php`.

I have tried and can't find the right hooks, and wasn't successful when I tried to create the file in my theme.

Anyone know how to customize templates in this plugin without editing the plugin itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comment in the answer [Overriding "Woocommerce Shipment Tracking" plugin templates files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915238/overriding-woocommerce-shipment-tracking-plugin-templates-files#comment82799881_47915705), should be correct as per the [changelog](https://dzv365zjfbd8v.cloudfront.net/changelogs/woocommerce-shipment-tracking/changelog.txt).

```
* Fix - Issue of template load order. Now it's overriden via yourtheme/woocommerce-shipment-tracking/{template_name}. For example storefront-child/woocommerce-shipment-tracking/myaccount/view-order.php.
```

If that isn't working, it sounds like a conflict - the WooCommerce.com team don't offer support for customizations.

Comment: Viola! In my case I use: /your-active-child-theme/woocommerce-shipment-tracking/email/tracking-info.php. Be aware, I did not need /templates/ and the subdirectory was /email/ not /emails/. Both, would be easy mistakes.